# Crash, Python and Google Calendar API

Tags: python, calendar, raspberry-pi2

Ahoy !

I followed the Documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python ) for google calendar API and this tutorial (http://www.esologic.com/?p=634 ) to create an alarm clock. The principle is quite simple. I put an event in my calendar, and if it is on the calendar "Raspberry" and that the description is "wake" when the time = the time specified, it plays me my music on the Pi.

Except that when I run my script, it will work for a variable time, and then will crash with a random error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alarmclock.py", line 65, in <module>
    calendar_event_query()
  File "alarmclock.py", line 37, in calendar_event_query
    events      = service.events().list(singleEvents=True, calendarId=CALENDAR_ID).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 722, in execute
    body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 596, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1272, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1036, in connect
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
    cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 891, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 566, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 788, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)
```

or

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alarmclock.py", line 80, in <module>
    calendar_event_query()
  File "alarmclock.py", line 52, in calendar_event_query
    events = service.events().list(singleEvents=True, calendarId=CALENDAR_ID).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 722, in execute
    body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 596, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1609, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1351, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1278, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

So I do not understand if it is a problem with my script, or if it is directly GoogleAPI that misfire and then crash my script?

Here is my script.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
import oauth2client
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools

from datetime import datetime
import logging
import time
import random
import os
import argparse

try:
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

CALENDAR_ID = 'MY_CALENDAR_ID@group.calendar.google.com'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'raspi-wake.json'
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
MP3_FOLDER = 'mp3'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def get_credentials():
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'raspberry-wake.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=SCOPE)
        flow.user_agent = 'Raspberry Wake'
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)

    return credentials


def calendar_event_query():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)

    today = datetime.today()
    events = service.events().list(singleEvents=True, calendarId=CALENDAR_ID).execute()

    for i, event in enumerate(events['items']):
        try:
            start = event['start']['dateTime'][:-9]
        except KeyError:
            start = ''

        description = event.get('description', '')
        now = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

        if start >= now and description.lower() == 'wake':
            if start == now:
                mp3_files = random.choice(os.listdir(MP3_FOLDER))
                command = 'mpg123 \'{}/{}\''.format(MP3_FOLDER, mp3_files)
                os.system(command)
                time.sleep(60)

while True:
    calendar_event_query()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Hard to specifically diagnose but if I was to hazard a guess - it looks like bad network connectivity vs. any issue with the script.

Comment: I really don't think it's a network issue because i use some others script connected to internet and they don't "crash" like this one....Or maybe a connection issue with google's server ? I restarted my script 3 hours ago, and still don't have any problem (for now)